# Difference between using cv=5 or cv=KFold(n_splits=5) in cross_val_score()?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

What is the difference between using `cv=5` or `cv=KFold(n_splits=5)` in `cross_val_score()`?

```
cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5)
```

> array([0.96666667, 0.96666667, 0.93333333, 0.93333333, 1.        ])

and

```
cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=KFold(n_splits=5))
```

> array([1.        , 1.        , 0.86666667, 0.93333333, 0.83333333])

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When an integer is passed to the `cv` parameter of [`cross_val_score()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html):

- `StratifiedKFold` is used if the estimator is a classifier and `y` is either binary or multiclass.
- In all other cases, `KFold` is used.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold, StratifiedKFold


data = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
x, y = data.data, data.target

print(cross_val_score(DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1), x, y, cv=5))
print(cross_val_score(DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1), x, y, cv=KFold(n_splits=5)))
print(cross_val_score(DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1), x, y, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)))
```

> [0.90434783 0.90434783 0.92035398 0.94690265 0.91150442]
>   [0.89473684 0.92982456 0.94736842 0.95614035 0.82300885]
>   [0.90434783 0.90434783 0.92035398 0.94690265 0.91150442]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! this was totally unexpected that the default cv= is already stratified.

Comment: @MeiNanZhu My pleasure. The information is found in the documentation of `cross_val_score()`. Please mark the answer as accepted if it satisfactorily answered your question.

Comment: sorry...where do i mark "Answered"? i don't see a button anywhere...i'm a bit new.

Comment: Click the green checkmark next to the triangle-shaped voting buttons.

Comment: It's strange that I found using ````cross_val_score(clf, features, targets, cv=n_cv)````  always yields much worse scores than ````skf = StratifiedKFold(shuffle=True, n_splits=n_cv)
    cv_results_s_k_fold = cross_val_score(clf, features, targets, cv=skf, scoring='accuracy')

````

Comment: @YuShen It's due to randomization. You should get the same results when you set `shuffle=False` in `StratifiedKFold` and fix the random state of the model or use a deterministic classifier.